# how to build a load more <li> function using pure javascript instead of jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, listview

I found this great code in codepen: http://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/wBYbgN

but i was trying to have the same feature using pure javascript , do anyone know if is that possible, and how could i achive that

thanks a lot

```js
var $parent = $("ul"),
    $items = $parent.find("li"),
    $loadMoreBtn = $("#load-more-comments"),
    maxItems = 10,
    hiddenClass = "visually-hidden";

  // add visually hidden class to items beyond maxItems
  $.each($items, function(idx,item){
      if(idx > maxItems - 1){
        $(this).addClass(hiddenClass);
      }
    });

  // onclick of show more button show more = maxItems
  // if there are none left to show kill show more button
  $loadMoreBtn.on("click", function(e){
      $("."+hiddenClass).each(function(idx,item){
        if(idx < maxItems - 1){
          $(this).removeClass(hiddenClass);
        }
        // kill button if no more to show
        if($("."+hiddenClass).size() === 0){
          $loadMoreBtn.hide();
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 1em;
}

.visually-hidden { 
  position: absolute; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
  height: 1px; width: 1px; 
  margin: -1px; padding: 0; border: 0; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul> 
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
    <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
  <li class="item">Item</li>
</ul>

<button id="load-more-comments">Load More</button>
```

Comment: As opposed to jquery? Your link to codepen is broken

Comment: http://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/wBYbgN , sorry for put the broken link ... just fixing....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here is a quick vanilla version of js code you provided

```
// cache vars

var parent = document.querySelector('ul'),
    items  = parent.querySelectorAll('li'),
    loadMoreBtn =  document.querySelector('#load-more-comments'),
    maxItems = 10,
    hiddenClass = "visually-hidden";


[].forEach.call(items, function(item, idx){
    if (idx > maxItems - 1) {
        item.classList.add(hiddenClass);
    }
});

loadMoreBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){

  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.' + hiddenClass), function(item, idx){
      console.log(item);
      if (idx < maxItems - 1) {
          item.classList.remove(hiddenClass);
      }

      if ( document.querySelectorAll('.' + hiddenClass).length === 0) {
          loadMoreBtn.style.display = 'none';
      }

  });

});
```

codepen with plain js:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpxPmN

here is the thing tho, jquery works out the different browsers' inconsistencies with things like adding event handlers, ajaxing, querying the DOM and such, so that's definitely the advantage of using it, especially if you are trying to write code that supports IE ;)

Comment: This is neat and concise.

Answer (score 1):

Everything that JQuery can do is possible with pure JavaScript, but I don't know why you'd want to use pure JS. JQuery is designed to speed up your coding process and help you to style your finished scripts better and make them more readable. Sure, if you write really good code you might get slight performance improvements, but probably a negligible amount for a project like this.

As for how you'd implement it, I'd suggest that you take a look at the JavaScript reference (hint - look at DOM interaction) and see if you can work it out for yourself, if you do decide to go down the pure JS route. You'll learn a lot more by working it out than you would by having someone on the internet write your code for you :)

Comment: Hi Barnaby, thanks for answer  , i am trying to avoid external libraries because, my website was loading 17 external js files... and sometimes a big library, only to make a small function... as i am learning about speed, i was thinking about having less js libraries and use more pure js ... i will try to do myself , but very beginner... thanks

Comment: 17 external js files, I would try to cut out some other ones before jquery

Comment: I see the issue - I'm pretty impressed you managed to have 17 JS files, especially as a beginner! If you really can't work it out, feel free to comment (preferably with some more specific questions) and I'll see if I can help you out without giving so much away that you're not working it out yourself!